# Initilizing structures containing bit-fields in C

Tags: c, initialization, variable-assignment, structure, bit-fields

Im trying to understand a bit more about the workings of bitfields.

Given the following code:
And assuming int is 32 bits

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct byte
    {
        int one:1;
    };
    struct byte var = {3};
    printf("%d\n", var.one);
    printf("%#x\n", var);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
-1
0x1
```

However I was expecting to see:

```
-1
0x3
```

Since

```
struct byte var = {3};
```

is assigning the value 3 to the 4 bytes of int, isn't it?

From the output I actually get it appears as if the above code line tries to store the value 3 into the 1 bit field hence printing `0x1` as the second output line.

So my question would be:

**How does these initializations and assignments on whole structures work?**

Also, why are the `{}` necessary?

Comment: Why would you expect that? You have a 1-bit-wide field that you assign to. The compiler is under no obligation to keep the extra bits.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan thank you for pointing that out. However, if the compiler is going to ignore the rest of the bits, why is it necessary to specify a type for each bitfield?

Comment: Try printing the sizes of `struct byte { TYPE var :1; };` with different types `(unsigned) int/char`. Quite possibly you will find a difference.

Comment: @pablorg: Primarily for ease of parsing/lexing during compilation. The compiler would need to know ahead of time if a structure's field were a bitfield before scanning the first word (which could be its name or its type.) Also because you can have signed or unsigned bitfields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int one:1;
```

With this, you declare an int with only one bit which is used for the `sign` bit. So you see `-1`.

If you want to store 3 (011), then you need to have 2 (data) +1(sign) bits in total. So, it should be:

```
struct byte
{
int one:3;
};
```

Or use an unsigned int.

```
struct byte
{
unsigned int one:2;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Maybe you can calrify something for me. What is the point of specifing a type for each bit-field if the compiler is going to ignore the unused bits anyway?

Comment: You requested one bit which is allocated. If you pass more than that, it ignores the extra bits of information.

Comment: so it makes no difference which type I use for the bit-field?

Comment: Yes, typically bitfileds are used to store one bit of flag for some purpose with something like `struct flags {unsigned int a:1; unsigned int b:1; unsigned int c:1};`.